# Dynamic Data Entity Framework missing Decimal Column

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm trying to build a Dynamic Data website to act as a simple admin interface to a MySQL database.

This isn't my area of expertise - but it all looks pretty straightforward when following the microsoft website.  However for some reason when using the Entity Data Model to the project, the `edmx` model is created, but doesn't read one of the tables correctly.

In the MySQL database I have a large table containing 9 columns.  The first column is the primary key and is an INT.  The remaining columns are of type `Decimal` with a length of 6,2.

The edmx file shows the INT column - but fails to read any of the `Decimal` columns.  If I change these to `VARCHAR` columns - everything is read perfectly?

The Dynamic Data Field Templates contains a control for decimals and surely the entity framework must be able to recognize columns of `DECIMAL` type - so I must be doing something wrong - I just can't work out what!

Any help much appreciated!
Cheers
Darren

Comment: OK - further info - although no errors are reported, there were messages generated in VS when the model is created -  stating that "Message 3 The data type 'udecimal' is not supported; the column 'Offline_International' in table 'fcukadmin.customer_fees' was excluded" . So I'm thinking that it's cannot understand the mySQL decimal format for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok -I discovered the answer myself!
The issue was due to using unsigned decimal values in the table structure.

Dynamic Data / Entity frame work does not recognise the decimal data type if the column is marked as unsigned.  When I changed this, the entity framework was able to read the DB structure correctly!

Hope this helps anyone else who comes across the same issue!

Cheers
Darren

Comment: what if I can't change the database column type?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Data / Entity frame work does not recognize the decimal data type if the column is marked as unsigned. When I changed this, the entity framework was able to read the DB structure correctly!

I got it with:

`Property(x => x.NameColumn).HasColumnName(@"NameColumn").HasColumnType("decimal").IsRequired().HasPrecision(9, 4)`